# cuda sparse operations in CSC format

Tags: cuda, sparse-matrix

I've been looking to use cuSPARSE to multiply a sparse matrix by a dense matrix. 
My sparse matrix is in CSC (Compressed Sparse Column Format). 
cuSPARSE supports conversion from CSC to CSR, and the multiplication in CSR format, but i've been looking for a solution that does not involve the CSC to CSR conversion. 
I would like to ask if someone knows of a library or something like it that implements this.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSC is CSR transposed. So just pass `CUSPARSE_OPERATION_TRANSPOSE` for `transA`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! do you also know which is more efficient? converting `csc2csr` or passing `CUSPARSE_OPERATION_TRANSPOSE`?

Comment: If you are doing multiple operations with the same data, I'd do the conversion first. With that being said, the times taken will depend on sparsity pattern. So there is no real good answer when comparing `csc2csr` and the `CUSPARSE_OPERATION_TRANSPOSE`